# Java 8 lambdas group list into map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to take a `List<Pojo>` and `return` a `Map<String, List<Pojo>>` where the `Map`'s key is a `String` value in `Pojo`, let's call it `String key`.

To clarify, given the following:

Pojo 1: Key:a value:1

Pojo 2: Key:a value:2

Pojo 3: Key:b value:3

Pojo 4: Key:b value:4

I want a `Map<String, List<Pojo>>` with `keySet()` sized 2, where key "a" has Pojos 1 and 2, and key "b" has pojos 3 and 4.

How could I best achieve this using Java 8 lambdas?

Comment: What’s the point of `mapping(Function.identity(), toList())`? `identity()` implies “no mapping” so why bother with a mapping collector then? Just replace it by a sole `toList()` and you end up with `groupingBy(t -> t.getKey(), HashMap::new, toList())` which pretty much describes the defaults of `groupingBy`, besides that the result is not guaranteed to be a `HashMap` when just using defaults. So when the defaults are appropriate (i.e. you don’t require a `HashMap`), use the defaults as shown in [Eran’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30756040/2711488)

Comment: Thanks @Holger, I realised the inadequacies of my code sample and removed it just before your comment appeared. You're absolutely right, thanks for your advice, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use the simple `groupingBy` variant:

```java
Map<String, List<Pojo>> map = pojos
  .stream()
  .collect(
     Collectors.groupingBy(Pojo::getKey)
  );
```

Answer (score 55):

Also, if you wanted to return a similar map but instead of whole Pojo you wanted the map's values be some property of the Pojo, you would do like that:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map = pojos
  .stream()
  .collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
      Employee::getKey,
      Collectors.mapping(
        Pojo::getSomeStringProperty, 
        Collectors.toList()
      )
    )
  );
```