# How to group List of Lists using a certain criteria in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a data structure like below. I'm trying to group the objects in such a way like `Map<String, List<String>>` where key is the entryId and value is the List of groups it belongs to. entryId is always unique inside a group.

Example: entryId "1111" belongs to group1,group2,group3. I'm using the old java 7 way to iterate through the lists and checking. Is there any best possible way using Java8 Collectors/grouping to achieve this.

`List<Group>` where each Group object will have a list of Entry objects.

```
    [  
   {  
      "id":"group1",
      "entries":[  
         {  
            "entryId":"1111",
            "name":"test1"
         },
         {  
            "entryId":"2222",
            "name":"test2"
         },
         {  
            "entryId":"3333",
            "name":"test3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"group2",
      "entries":[  
         {  
            "entryId":"4444",
            "name":"test1"
         },
         {  
            "entryId":"1111",
            "name":"test2"
         },
         {  
            "entryId":"2222",
            "name":"test3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"group3",
      "entries":[  
         {  
            "entryId":"1111",
            "name":"test1"
         },
         {  
            "entryId":"5555",
            "name":"test2"
         },
         {  
            "entryId":"3333",
            "name":"test3"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So the expected out put is this :

```
    [  
   {  
      "1111":[  
         "group1",
         "group2",
         "group3"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "2222":[  
         "group1",
         "group2"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "3333":[  
         "group1",
         "group3"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "4444":[  
         "group2"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "5555":[  
         "group3"
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm using below way currently. which is working as expected, but is there a much simpler way in Java 8 I can achieve this.

```
    public Map<String, List<String>> mapEntries(List<Group> groups) {
    Map<String, List<String>> entryMaps = new HashMap<>();
    for (Group group : groups) {
        for (Entry entry : group.getEntries()) {
            List<String> groupsEntryBelongs = new ArrayList<>();
            if (groups.iterator().hasNext() && !entryMaps.keySet().contains(entry.getEntryId())) {
                updateGroups(groups, entry.getEntryId(), groupsEntryBelongs, entryMaps);
            }
        }
    }
    return entryMaps;
}

    void updateGroups(List<Group> groups, String id, List<String> groupsEntryBelongs, Map<String, List<String>> entryMaps) {
        for (Group group : groups) {
            for (Entry entry : group.getEntries()) {
                if (entry.getEntryId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                    groupsEntryBelongs.add(group.getId());
                }
            }
        }
        entryMaps.put(id, groupsEntryBelongs);
    }
```

Comment: I used the way to iterate through the groups and getting the first entry id and then checking through the remaining groups to update the object Map<String, List<String>> I created. I 'm getting the results I need, but asking for suggestions to implement it in java8.

Comment: Its always worth sharing what you've tried in the question to bring the clarity about your expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 lambdas group list into map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755949/java-8-lambdas-group-list-into-map)

Comment: @uli no, its not what I'm looking for. I updated my question with the expected output and the way I'm doing it currently. The one you pointed is different. I'm trying to do the grouping by the values inside the inner lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> entryMaps = new LinkedHashMap<>();
groups.forEach(group -> 
    group.getEntries().forEach(entry -> 
            entryMaps.computeIfAbsent(
                    entry.getEntryId().toLowerCase(),
                    k -> new LinkedHashSet<>())
                .add(group.getId())));
```

This iterates the groups, then each group's entries and uses `Map.computeIfAbsent` to put an entry with a new, empty `LinkedHashSet` if the key wasn't present, returning either this empty set or the one matching that key. Then, the group id is added to this returned set.

Note: I'm using a `Set` instead of a `List` for values, to avoid possible duplicates. And `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedhashSet` guarantee insertion-order.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. based on your implementation I had to declare as this.
Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> entryMaps = new LinkedHashMap<>()

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work, it requires making some sort of intermediate tuple object:

```java
groups.stream()
    .flatMap(group -> group.getEntries().stream()
            .map(entry -> Map.entry(entry.getEntryId(), group.getId())))
    .collect(Colectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
            Colectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<List<EmployeeHourLogDetails>> resultLisSalesman = new ArrayList<> 
(employeeHourLogHeader.getEmployeeHourLogDetails().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> 
d.getEmployeeId())).values());
```

Comment: could you add some explanation to it, please?