# Groupby counts in java

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am pretty new to java moving from c#. I have the following class.

```
class Resource {
    String name;
    String category;
    String component;
    String group;
}
```

I want to know the following numbers:
1. Count of resources in the category.
2. Distinct count of components in each category. (component names can be duplicate)
3. Count of resources grouped by category and group.

I was able to achieve a little bit of success using `Collectors.groupingBy`. However, the result is always like this.

```
Map<String, List<Resource>>
```

To get the counts I have to parse the keyset and compute the sizes.
Using c# linq, I can easily compute all the above metrics.
I am assuming there is definitely a better way to do this in java as well. Please advise.

Comment: for #1, are you saying given a specific category, how many `Resource` objects have that specific category?

Comment: You should be using another overload of groupingBy, e.g. `groupingBy(Resource::getCategory, Collectors.counting())`

Comment: Check this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755949/java-8-lambdas-group-list-into-map

Comment: @ChrisGong - Correct

Comment: @LouisWasserman - the overload won't work for 2. counting() doesn't take parameters.

Comment: @Anan `groupingBy` can accept a downstream `Collector` further to groupBy again on the `component` and count them - `Collectors.groupingBy(Resource::getCategory, Collectors.groupingBy(Resource::getComponent, Collectors.counting()))`. Aside : Just wondering, using C# were you able to attain all three of those in a single statement? Is that the expectation here as well? It would make the question much clear to see what you've tried in java so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, I'd use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) along with [`Collectors.counting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--):

```
Map<String, Long> resourcesByCategoryCount = resources.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 Resource::getCategory,
                 Collectors.counting()));
```

This groups `Resource` elements by `category`, *counting* how many of them belong to each category.

For #2, I wouldn't use streams. Instead, I'd use the [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) operation (introduced in Java 8):

```
Map<String, Set<String>> distinctComponentsByCategory = new LinkedHashMap<>();
resources.forEach(r -> distinctComponentsByCategory.computeIfAbsent(
                       r.getCategory(),
                       k -> new HashSet<>())
         .add(r.getGroup()));
```

This first creates a `LinkedHashMap` (which preserves *insertion order*). Then, `Resource` elements are iterated and put into this map in such a way that they are grouped by `category` and each `group` is added to a `HashSet` that is mapped to each category. As sets don't allow duplicates, there won't be duplicated groups for any category. Then, the distinct count of groups is the size of each set.

For #3, I'd again use `Collectors.groupingBy` along with `Collectors.counting`, but I'd use a *composite key* to group by:

```
Map<List<String>, Long> resourcesByCategoryAndGroup = resources.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 r -> Arrays.asList(r.getCategory(), r.getGroup()), // or List.of
                 Collectors.counting()));
```

This groups `Resource` elements by `category` and `group`, *counting* how many of them belong to each `(category, group)` pair. For the grouping key, a two-element `List<String>` is being used, with the `category` being its 1st element and the `component` being its 2nd element.

Or, instead of using a composite key, you could use nested grouping:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> resourcesByCategoryAndGroup = resources.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 Resource::getCategory,
                 Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Resource::getGroup,
                            Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: Will do. I am just waiting for your response about #2 :).

Comment: Thanks Federico again. I wish there is a good way to combine the two step operation into 1 step. Oh well!!

Comment: @Anan The one-liner which uses streams for #2 is longer and less readable than this 2-line solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fedrico for detailed response. #1 and #3 worked great. For #2, i would like to see an output of Map. Here's the code that i am using currently to get that count. This is without using collectors in old style.

```
    HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Resource resource : resources) {
            if (map.containsKey(resource.getCategory())) {
                map.get(resource.getCategory()).add(resource.getGroup());
            } else 
                HashSet<String> componentSet = new HashSet<>();
                componentSet.add(resource.getGroup());
                map.put(resource.getCategory(), componentSet);
            }
        }

        log.info("Group count in each category");
        for (Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            log.info("{} - {}", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size());
        }
```

Comment: I'd remove this answer, because it might receive negative votes from other users. I'd add this to the original question